# "autoKeyInfo is not initialized" when trying to batch insert into table with generated id

Tags: oracle, jdbc

When I tried to upgrade my Oracle JDBC driver from `ojdbc8 19.6.0.0` to `ojdbc11 21.6.0.0.1` I started to receive the following exception when trying to do a batch insert with ids being generated in the database:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: autoKeyInfo is not initialized
```

[I created a reproducer for this.](https://github.com/schauder/stackoverflow/tree/main/jdbc/oracle-autokeyinfo)

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the later versions of the Oracle JDBC drivers.
They have the findings in the issue tracker, but I have nothing to link to since it is not public.

The recommended workaround is to use the LTS driver version, which is `ojdbc 19.15.0.0.1`

***Version `23.3.0.23.09` works fine again.***

### Versions tested

#### Not working

- 21.9.0.0
- 21.6.0.0.1

#### Working

- 19.15.0.0.1
- 19.18.0.0

Answer (score 1):

The reproducer is not just doing a batch update, it uses a Keyholder and tries to return the IDs generated by the database. The problem is not the generation of values, the problem is the attempt to return them.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/jjdbc/Oracle-extensions.html#GUID-9EC82134-1206-4325-A17B-9FA7610F0169 says "DML returning cannot be combined with batch update". "DML returning" refers to "returning into" clauses used by the driver to return values for out parameters. Looks like a conscious regression in the newer driver versions. Spring uses Keyholders to handle out parameters.

When creating the keys in the database with identity columns or triggers or with <sequence>.nextval in the SQL statement and not trying to return it the generated value, batch inserts should work.

Comment: I'm not using DML returning.

Comment: You do implicitly: your reproducer uses a Keyholder and tries to return the IDs generated by the database. The problem is not the generation of values, the problem is the attempt to return them. If you create the keys in the database with identity columns or triggers or with `<sequence>.nextval` in the SQL statement and don't try to return it the generated value, batch inserts should work.

Comment: I recommend to [edit] that explanation from comment into the answer itself. It would benefit generally and specifically give less of an impression of being mostly a link.

Comment: Merged. Thx for the hint.